# Autohotkey - Duplicate Selected Lines Down

Tags: netbeans, macros, autohotkey

i want to simulate a Netbeans feature. I want to be able to duplicate the selected LINES. (not the selected text).

I have written the following AutoHotkey macro

```
DuplicateDown()
{
    SetKeyDelay, -1
    Temp := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard =
    Send {Home}+{End}^c
    ClipWait, 2
    Send {End}{Enter}%Clipboard%
    Clipboard := Temp
}
```

Problem is that this macro only copies the current line. and i want to be able to copy multiple selected lines.

Can you please advise me how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the lines selected upfront and then send {Home}+{End}, don't you force the system to re-select a single line instead of the previously selected mutiple lines?

Here is an example, it does not work with automatic line-breaks though....

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
Insert::
    Temp := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard = ""
    Send, ^c
    Sleep, 300
    loop, parse, clipboard, `n
        Jump:=a_index - 1
    Send {End}+{Home}
    Send, +{Up %Jump%}^c
    ClipWait, 2
    Send {Down %Jump%}
    Send, {End}{Enter}^v
    Clipboard := Temp
Return
```

Comment: Yes this is the case now, as i say the following is only for a one line copy. i would like to improve my script as to be able to select multiple lines. and if i remove the {Home}+{End} then it will only copy the selected text. I want to copy the selected lines

Comment: Even though i don't select the entire line from start to end. the entire line's content should be duplicated. so even if my mouse pointer is just on a line (without selecting anything) and the shortcut is pressed the line should be duplicated. same goes for multi-line selection even if not all the text is selected the entire line should be duplicated. this is the way that Netbeans does it. and i have goten used to it. so i want to recreate it for all my other aps

Comment: Would a solution be to check how many line-breaks are stored in the clipBoard, then go to the end of the last line (End), Select the whole last line (+Home) and move up (+up) as many lines as there are line-breaks?

Comment: how can i go to the end of the last selected line, {End} does not  go to the end of the last selected line but only to the last of the current line. (the difference comes in when selecting up, instead of down)

Comment: I think that you will have to choose which way you want to select your lines. If you always select from bottom to top, you'll have to reverse the procedure. Otherwise you will have to first copy the data, then check around the caret if the first word left or right of the caret is at the front or end of the clipboard data to see if your caret is at the start or the end of the selected data.